# How to use Tortoise overlays on my own files

Tags: windows, icons, overlay

Windows can only use limited number of overlays [15 total, 11 after what Windows uses](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/faq.html#ovlnotshowing) so I want to use the existing ones on my own files.

The location of those overlays is `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers`

I want to do something like custom dropbox and I want to show green check when file is updated and red exclamation when file not synced yet. How I can do that?

Comment: If its too broad give me one solution because I can't find any